# Python nested list of integers not returning as expected

Tags: python, list, types

I'm writing this function that checks if a list of lists would be a valid sudoku puzzle.  When I'm checking the lists for valid integers I'm getting unexpected results.

For example:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[4,2,1]]
for i in lst: 
  for v in i:
    print type(v)

<type 'int'>   #all the way through

for i in lst:
  for v in i:
    if v is int:
      print True
```

Prints nothing, and when I through in:

```
for i in lst:
  for v in i:
    if v is not int:
      print False
```

Prints all False? Not sure about what is going on, especially with the type showing they're integers.

Comment: Is the orange in my hand the same thing as the concept of oranges?

Comment: I wish `is` in python worked this way. They should've used `===` for equivalence and `is` for `isinstance`.

Comment: @thg435 Really? How frequently do you write type checks, as against test for identity?

Comment: @Marcin: I don't use either very often. `if param is int` just sounds better to me than `isinstance`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of saying

```
if v is int:
```

Which is asking if v is the actual type int

Say

```
if isinstance(v, int):
```

which says v is an instantiated `int` (or subclass)

Here is an example, first with an integer (or instantiated `int`)

```
>>> v = 17
>>> type(v)
<type 'int'>
>>> v is int
False
>>> isinstance(v, int)
True
>>>
```

Next with a type

```
>>> v = int
>>> type(v)
<type 'type'>
>>> v is int
True
>>> isinstance(v, int)
False
>>>
```

Comment: Hey thanks Nick, just to be clear, this is because v is an instantiated 'type' int and not directly assigned?

Comment: Yes `v` is an instantiated `int`, not the type `int`.  I added an example to the answer to hopefully make things clearer

Answer (score 2):

No integer is the same object as `int`. You want to use `isintance`.

You *don't* want to use `type(v) == int`, because that will evaluate to False if `v` is a subclass of `int`, which is in most cases not the desired behaviour at all; if you do really, really want that, do `type(v) is int`, because `is` is the expected style for comparison with a specific object (which is what a type is).

Answer (score 2):

```
v is not int
```

is the same as saying, but a more readable version of

```
not v is int
```

`is` compares the references of each operand (not the types) to see if they are the same. Here is an example of that:

```
>>> x = (1,2,3)
>>> y = (1,2,3)
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
```

So `v is int` obviously evaluates to `False`. `not` turns `False` into `True` and the if statement prints.

Use `isinstance(v, int)` for the correct result.

Comment: Very helpful, this is expanding on what Marcin had commented, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answers saying you should use isinstance are correct, but an alternative way to do it would be to use `if type(v) == int`.

Comment: Thank you and your comment fit in nicely with the others explanation.

Comment: `isinstance` does not do the same thing as `type(v) == int`. `isinstance(v,t)` will report `True` if `type(v)` evalutes to `t` or to any subclass of `t`.

Comment: @Marcin: I did not claim this was equivalent to isinstance, I said this was an alternative way to do what OP wanted to do. Subclasses are  irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @Junuxx Unless...unless...the example code in the question is not the only code OP will ever write.

Comment: @Marcin: Unless... unless there might be actual instances of subclasses of `int` in the data that should not pass, e.g., `True` and `False`. I'm not convinced.

Comment: @Junuxx Why shouldn't they pass? In any case, your answer rather lacks for any hint of such reasoning.

Comment: LOL you downvoted my answer. It doesn't make yours any better.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm annoyed and offended by your aggressive tone now. I indicated that I was only offering an alternative, I added onto the options available to the OP, your own answer was less complete rather than more and you didn't give a reason for the downvote.

Comment: @Junuxx No, you're annoyed and offended that I've pointed out that your answer is incorrect on several levels.

Comment: @Marcin: No, you could just have pointed out the difference and say that it might not be the best option depending on the context. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Junuxx I did just that, then you were so annoyed and offended that you had to try to find a reason that I was wrong.